# Create keyboard shortcuts using a combination of 2 Keys

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, when the `25` Keys are pressed in my Main Form, `Form1` should open.
While pressing, e.g., `2a`, should open `Form2`.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    Dim q As Queue(Of string) = New Queue(Of string)()
    q.Enqueue(e.keychar)  
    q.Enqueue(e.keychar)
    For Each element As string In q
        If element = "25" Then
            Form2.Show()
            If element = "2a" Then
                Form3.Show()
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: There's only **ONE** key. How can you get `2a`, which is two values? Is this hex notation, or do you want to check this across two keypress events?

Comment: I want to check this through two keypress events ,i want to compare with the words if correct show my form

Comment: You may want to reconsider your key combinations. Do you have a main form? If so, add a `MenuStrip` to the main form. Then add a ToolStripMenuItem named "Forms". In the properties, set `Visible=false`. Under "Forms" (in the menu), add "Form 1", "Form 2", etc. In the MenuStrip, select "Form 1". In properties, set `ShowShortcutKeys = True`, then click on `ShortcutKeys` and select the desired key combination to open Form1. Repeat for the other forms.

Answer (score 1):

Following the logic that uses a Queue (maybe that's what you need to use), you can build a class objects that handles these key presses and perform an Action when a known combination is found.

I'm using a `Dictionary(Of Integer, Action)` to store the `Keys` combination and map an Action to each combination.
When a combination of keys if found, `Action?.Invoke()` is called, to create a new instance of a Form class.

To get the keys pressed in the Form you use for this, I'm overriding [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey). This method is called whenever a Key is pressed. Note that all keys are *intercepted*, including those directed to child Controls.
So, if you write, e.g., `25` in a TextBox, `Form1` will open.
If this is not what you want, add a Boolean Field that disables the key processing when a writable child Control receives the Focus.

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private keyPressHandler As New DoubleKeyPressHandler()

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        keyPressHandler.Add(keyData)
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function
End Class
```

You can add new Actions (e.g., add a `3M` combination that opens `Form4`):

```
keyPressHandler.Actions.Add(Keys.D3 << 16 Or Keys.M, Sub() Call New Form4().Show())
```

**`DoubleKeyPressHandler` helper class:**

The class treats each combination of Keys as the High/Low 16 bit *sections* of an Integer, so one Key *occupies* the High Word (bits from 16 to 31) and the other the Lower Word (bits from 0 to 15).

You can have only `Dim dKey = keyQueue.Dequeue << 16 Or keyQueue.Dequeue` if you don't want to cache the second Key press of an unmatched combination.
In this case, also remove the `Else` block in `TryMapKeys()`.

```
Friend Class DoubleKeyPressHandler
    Private keyQueue As New Queue(Of Keys)
    Public Sub New()
        Actions = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Action) From {
            {Keys.D2 << 16 Or Keys.D5, Sub() Call New Form1().Show()},
            {Keys.D2 << 16 Or Keys.A, Sub() Call New Form2().Show()}
        }
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Actions As Dictionary(Of Integer, Action)

    Public Sub Add(key As Keys)
        keyQueue.Enqueue(key)
        TryMapKeys()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TryMapKeys()
        If keyQueue.Count < 2 Then Return
        Dim key1 = keyQueue.Dequeue
        Dim key2 = keyQueue.Dequeue
        Dim dKey = key1 << 16 Or key2
        Dim keyAction As Action = Nothing
        If Actions.TryGetValue(dKey, keyAction) Then
            keyAction?.Invoke()
        Else
            ' If the combination is not a match, the last Key is added back
            ' Remove the Else block if you prefer to cancel it instead. Test it.
            keyQueue.Enqueue(key2)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should pick an answer and mark it as the *good one* (the one you prefer), so it will close the *issue*.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `Imports System.Reactive.Linq` - then you can do this:

```
Public Class Main
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        Dim factories = New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Form))() From
            {
                {"25", Function() New Form1()},
                {"2a", Function() New Form2()}
            }

        _subscription =
            Observable. 
                FromEventPattern(Of KeyPressEventHandler, KeyPressEventArgs)(
                    Sub(h) AddHandler Me.KeyPress, h,
                    Sub(h) RemoveHandler Me.KeyPress, h). 
                Buffer(2).
                Select(Function(x) New String(x.[Select](Function(y) y.EventArgs.KeyChar).ToArray())).
                Where(Function(x) factories.ContainsKey(x)). 
                ObserveOn(Me).
                Select(Function(x) factories(x).Invoke()).
                Subscribe(Sub(f) f.Show())
    End Sub

    Private _subscription As IDisposable = Nothing
End Class
```

Now you can add as many key pairs as you need in the `factories` dictionary.

Just call `_subscription.Dispose()` to clean up when you close the form.

Comment: I'm glad that you contributed to the thread, but the syntax looks like a mashup of TypeScript, C#, and Visual Basic. My very opinionated take is that not only did you over-engineer a solution but you made it practically unreadable; and I'm the type of guy who prefers a LINQ style syntax over traditional looping mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
I am using version 2010 and there is no Imports System.Reactive.Linq please help me

Comment: @mostafabarzegar - You need to NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and then add `Imports System.Reactive.Linq` to the top of your code.

Comment: @David - Let's blame the syntax for lambdas in VB.NET. Compared to C# syntax it's terrible. I certainly understand why VB developers would think it's "a mashup of TypeScript, C#, and Visual Basic".

Comment: I don’t do very much VB.NET development anymore, in fact it’s mostly C# and Angular, I’m just saying that your solution is unnecessarily over-engineered; not to mention you could have used a query style syntax to dramatically improve readability without sacrificing performance.

Comment: @David - I disagree that it's over-engineered. Rx vastly simplifies all sorts of event-like data queries. There is a learning curve to understand the operators, but it's made the whole thing a single encapsulated line of code. It's beautifully engineered. It just takes time to understand the beauty. I chose not to use the query syntax because of the `Buffer` and `ObserveOn` operators.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn This code gives the NullReferenceException error

Comment: @mostafabarzegar - Are you saying my code throws a `NullReferenceException`? It shouldn't do. I tested it before posting.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - i call _subscription in event keypress gives the NullReferenceException  was unhandled error

Comment: @mostafabarzegar - Why are you asking Joel?

Comment: @Enigmativity hi Because it gives me the answer

Comment: @Enigmativity--i call _subscription in event keypress gives the NullReferenceException was unhandled error

Comment: What does "call `_subscription`" mean? `_subscription` is an object of type `IDisposable`. You can't call an object. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. You're adding the same keychar to the collection twice
2. Because the collection is defined within the scope of KeyPress, it will be empty the next time the event gets fired
3. You are iterating over the collection and checking if the currently iterated value equals two different values (which will never be true)
4. You are comparing a Char value against a String value (which will never be true)
5. KeyChars represent ASCII characters, but it looks like you want to compare hexadecimal values

It's not exactly obvious what you want to do, but if you're wanting to show `Form2` when the keychar equals the percent character or `Form3` when the keychar equals the star character, then remove everything you currently have and use just a simple If/Then:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = "%"c Then
        Form2.Show()
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "*"c Then
        Form3.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to show form3 when I press key 2 and then a, which combines 2a

Comment: Can you help me because I am a beginner

Comment: What kind of typist do you expect? Is it okay if someone presses "2", walks away, and then comes back and presses "a" after a few minutes?